# Power BI C# API: How to update refreshSchedule of the datasets?

Tags: c#, azure, dataset, powerbi

Below is error that I could not update refreshSchedule of the datasets:

> {
>        "error": {
>               "code": "InvalidRequest",
>               "message": "Invalid NotifyOption value 'MailOnFailure' for app only owner requests"
>        }
>   }

Below is code to call it:

```
var datasets = await client.Datasets.GetDatasetsAsync(new Guid(_workspaceId));
var days = new List<Days?> { Days.Monday, Days.Tuesday, Days.Wednesday, Days.Thursday, Days.Friday, Days.Saturday, Days.Sunday };
var times = new List<string> { "00:00" };
var refreshSchedule = new RefreshSchedule(days, times, true, "UTC");
var id = "XXX";

await client.Datasets.TakeOverAsync(new Guid(_workspaceId), id);
var refreshRequest = new RefreshRequest(NotifyOption.NoNotification);
// refresh datasets
await client.Datasets.RefreshDatasetAsync(new Guid(_workspaceId), id, refreshRequest);
// Target: Update RefreshSchedule (Exception for calling this)
await client.Datasets.UpdateRefreshScheduleInGroupAsync(new Guid(_workspaceId), id, refreshSchedule);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you pls let me know how the app is consuming the endpoint - User Interventaion or Completeley done through AppOnly or using the master user Credential?

Alternatively, if you don't want the **MailOnfailure**, can you set up explicitly No Notification  for the Refresh Schedule and Try ?

just modified your piece of code and presented below :

```
 var refreshSchedule = new RefreshSchedule(days, times, true, "UTC", ScheduleNotifyOption.NoNotification);
```

The snippet :

```
var days = new List<Days?> { Days.Monday, Days.Tuesday, Days.Wednesday, Days.Thursday, Days.Friday, Days.Saturday, Days.Sunday };
var times = new List<string> { "00:00" };
//Fixed code
var refreshSchedule = new RefreshSchedule(days, times, true, "UTC", ScheduleNotifyOption.NoNotification);

await client.Datasets.UpdateRefreshScheduleInGroupAsync(WorkspaceId, datasets.Id, refreshSchedule);
```

**UPDATE**

When i used ServicePrincipal (without any UserIntervention/Master User Credential)

I was able to repro your issue

> Error
> Status: BadRequest (400) Response: {"error":{"code":"InvalidRequest","message":"Invalid NotifyOption
> value 'MailOnFailure' for app only owner requests"}}

I was able to get past the error by making use of the **ScheduleNotifyOption.NoNotification** in the refreshSchedule mentioned above.

[image]

Or if i use the app through cred of a mailenabled account.

Comment: Thanks @sathya_vijayakumar-MSFT. After I granted privilege to ServicePrincipal in PowerBI console and using your suggested method `ScheduleNotifyOption.NoNotification`, it is okay to update RefreshSchedule now.